# Why isn't there a endWith operator in Rx?

Tags: rxjs, observable

Having such a convenient method like `.startWith` it would make sense to have his oposite, `.endWith`, which makes the observable yield a value whenever it gets completed.

I have come up with this solution, but is there anything better? This thing gets a bit hard to read for what it is.

```
source.concat(Rx.Observable.just(lastValue))
```

Comment: You're doing it the right way. There's no `endWith` because `cocnat` is exactly what it does already. Note that there's also `defaultIfEmpty` with a similar purpose.

Comment: @martin Actually, for my specific case `defaultIfEmpty` is enough. Haven't noticed that operator, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is in RxJS6 (no clue when it was added to be honest)

**Documentation**:

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/endWith

**Source:** https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/df0ea7c78767c07a6ed839608af5a7bb4cefbde5/src/internal/operators/endWith.ts

Also, `defaultIfEmpty()` only emits a value if the observable CLOSES without emitting a value. It's a subtle, yet not so subtle distinction. It may have the same effect as `endWith()` in limited situations.

**Example of endWith():**

```
const source = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
const example = source.pipe(
                            takeWhile(val => val != 4), 
                            endWith(4));
```

Emits:

> [1, 2, 3, 4]

Also I'm noticing that the https://learnrxjs.io website is increasingly out of date, and currently doesn't show this operator.

**Why did I need it?**

I was looking for the ability to emit `false` until a condition became `true`, but never go back to false. So slightly similar to debouncing, but not quite.